# ¿Cómo deshabilitar el boton cuando los input no tengan cambios?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un formulario con datos cargados en los respectivos input y lo que quiero es que cuando no existan cambios en los input el boton se mantenga deshabilitado pero si existen cambios se habilite el boton.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            metodos.CambioInputValor();
        });

        var metodos = function(){
            return{
                CambioInputValor:function(){
                    var inivalNombre = $("#idNombre").val();
                    $("#idNombre").on('input',function(){
                        if ( $("#idNombre").val() != inivalNombre ) {
                            $("#btnActualizar").attr('disabled',false);
                        }else{
                            $("#btnActualizar").attr('disabled',true);
                        }
                    });

                    var inivalEdad = $("#idEdad").val();
                    $("#idEdad").on('input',function(){
                        if ( $("#idEdad").val() != inivalEdad ) {
                            $("#btnActualizar").attr('disabled',false);
                        }else{
                            $("#btnActualizar").attr('disabled',true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container mb-10">
        <form action="" id="idForm">
            <div class="row col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="idNombre">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" id="idNombre" value="Darwin" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="IdEdad">Edad</label>
                    <input type="text" id="idEdad"  value="27" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnActualizar">Actualizar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Creo que ya lo tienes hecho, solo agrega este atributo a tu etiqueta btnActualizar: disabled = "false"

Comment: El problema es que si hice cambios a los 2 input y luego a uno de ellos lo vuelvo a como esta antes no debería deshabilitarse el boton hasta que ninguno tenga cambios.Solo debería deshabilitarse cuando ninguno haya sufrido cambios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
    var metodos = function(){
        return{
            CambioInputValor:function(){
                var inivalNombre = $("#idNombre").val();
                var inivalEdad = $("#idEdad").val();

                $("#idNombre").on('input',function(){
                    if ( $("#idNombre").val() != inivalNombre || $("#idEdad").val() != inivalEdad) {
                        $("#btnActualizar").attr('disabled',false);
                    }else{
                        $("#btnActualizar").attr('disabled',true);
                    }
                });

                $("#idEdad").on('input',function(){
                    if ( $("#idNombre").val() != inivalNombre || $("#idEdad").val() != inivalEdad) {
                        $("#btnActualizar").attr('disabled',false);
                    }else{
                        $("#btnActualizar").attr('disabled',true);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled = "false" id="btnActualizar">Actualizar</button>
```

Comment: @Dum, si necesitas algo adicional, me comentas.